# What is the logic behind flags and methods?

Tags: powershell

For example:

```
> "a,b,c" -split ","
a
b
c

> "a,b,c".split(",")
a
b
c

> "a,b,c".length
5

> "a,b,c" -length
At line:1 char:9
+ "a,b,c" -length
+         ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-length' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

So not every method can be expressed as an flag/argument list. I'm not even sure that `.split` and `-split` are the same thing or whether this is by chance.

When should I expect to use a flag and when a method? How do I discover all flags available (for a string, a number, etc.

Another thing is that `ls -?` returns a help text, but `"foo" -?` doesn't. So while it accepts flags, it is not really treated as a command

Comment: `-split` is not flag. It is operator: `Get-Help about_Operators`.

Comment: And no, `Split()` and `-split` don't to the same thing. The former splits a string at any of the characters in the argument, the latter splits a string at the given regular expression. In your case it just looks like they do the same, because you're splitting at a single character with no special meaning in a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It boils down to this.

This ... "a,b,c" -length

About Operators
An operator is a language element that you can use in a command or expression. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1
Because there are several operator types, the above is not a single source doc reference.

Vs this... "a,b,c".length

About methods
Describes how to use methods to perform actions on objects in PowerShell.
Methods allow you to examine, compare and format many properties of a PowerShell Object, perform an action.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods?view=powershell-5.1

From your example :

String.Split Method
Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

About Split 
The Split operator splits one or more strings into substrings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-5.1

String.Length Property
The Length property returns the number of Char objects in this instance, not the number of Unicode characters.

You'll note if you open this in the PowerShell_ISE.exe or VSCode, you'll see right away, the item 4 is immediately shown as an syntax error even before you run. This is denoted by the red squiggle. That marker means it will never work, so no real reason to try it.

Just because you can type it, does not make it right. If you type a '-' after a space for anything you get a list of what is expected. Well, if you are in the PowerShel_ISE or Visual Studio Code. If you are in the PowerShell console host, you have to hit the tab key to tab through the list or use CRTL + Spacebar to see the full list, then tab or arrow to what you want to use.

```
('a,b,c').length # this is an array, and this is returning the count of the elements in the array
5
('a,b,c','d,e,f').length # note the element count difference
2

('a,b,c').Length # property use of a .Net class
5

('a,b,c') -length # attempted unknown / invalid switch (PowerShell operator)
```

To know what you can and cannot do to an object or how, you have to what it supports. That is what Get-Member is for.

So the Array allows this..

```
('a,b,c') | Get-Member
```

and this..

```
('abc')   | Get-Member

Most common listed 

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
...
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count), string[] Sp...
...
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)                      
...
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(cultureinfo culture)                                               
...
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string IConvertible.ToString...
...
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(cultureinfo culture)
...
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}
Length           Property              int Length {get;}
```

As for this...
When should I expect to use a flag and when a method? 
How do I discover all flags available (for a string, a number, etc.

You have to read the help file on the cmdlet you are trying to use, or at minimum it's examples.

```
    Get-Help -Name Get-ItemProperty -Full

    Get-Help -Name Get-ItemProperty -Examples
```

Then info on the cmdlet / function you are trying to use

```
    (Get-Command -Name Get-ItemProperty).Parameters 
     switches (flags) which will expect a value to the right of it or not, see the property values line below
```

Then what you can use the cmdlet/function on.

```
    Get-ItemProperty -Path D:\Temp | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
    Get-ItemProperty -Path D:\Temp | Format-List
    Get-ItemProperty -Path D:\Temp | Format-List -Force
    Get-ItemProperty -Path D:\Temp | Select-Object -Property * # property values
    (Get-ItemProperty -Path D:\Temp) | Get-Member
```

As for this...
Another thing is that ls -? returns a help text, but "foo" -? doesn't. 
So while it accepts flags, it is not really treated as a command

Foo is not a valid name of anything in PowerShell, unless you created a foo function or module. So, it should hot return anything.
Again, just because you can type it, does not make it correct.

In most cases, if you are doing the above and you do not get automatic intellisense, then what you are doing is probably wrong.

To see all the cmdlets, functions, etc you have on your system for use. You do this.

```
Get-Command
```

Comment: Your explanation of why `"foo" -?` doesn't work is incorrect. The actual reason is that PowerShell doesn't interpret strings as commands unless you use the call operator (`&`). Bare strings are automatically echoed to the success output stream. If you put something beginning with a hyphen after a string that gets interpreted as an operator (but an operator `-?` doesn't exist). `& "foo" -?` would work if `foo` were a valid command. Compare for instance the output of `"Copy-Item" -?` and `& "Copy-Item" -?`.